# Trouble getting custom unity event to fire

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I'm coding a game where customers will be spawned in, go to a table, then wait a few seconds and go back to their spawn position. When that happens, I want to delete them and fire off an event that tells another script to spawn more in. In my code, I have everything working but when I try to Invoke the event, nothing happens.

On my CustomerMovement script, I create the event and fire it off (OnCustomerLeaves)
On my CustomerSpawnManager script, I grab the CustomerMovement script and create a listner to the OnCustomerLeaves event. I have a log place holder there for now but nothing gets printed to the console so I'm guessing the event just isn't firing.

Heres where I create the event and invoke it

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event EventHandler OnCustomerLeaves;

    private Vector3 startingPos;

    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> seatingOptionsList;
    private GameObject seatingSpot;
    private bool atSpot = false;

    private float speedValue = 3.0f;
    private float speed;
    private float waitTimer = 5.0f;



    private void Start()
    {
        startingPos = transform.position;

        PickRandomSeat();
    }



    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMovement();     
    }



    private void PickRandomSeat()
    {
        int randomSeatingSpot = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, seatingOptionsList.Count);
        seatingSpot = seatingOptionsList[randomSeatingSpot];

    }



    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        

        if (atSpot == false)
        {
            speed = speedValue * Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 modSeatingPosition = new Vector3(seatingSpot.transform.position.x, seatingSpot.transform.position.y + 1, seatingSpot.transform.position.z);

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, modSeatingPosition, speed);
            
            if (transform.position == modSeatingPosition)
            {
                atSpot = true;
            }
        }
        if (atSpot == true)
        {
            waitTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (waitTimer <= 0)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, startingPos, speed);

                if (transform.position == startingPos)
                {
                    DestroyCustomer();

                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void DestroyCustomer()
    {
        OnCustomerLeaves?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        Debug.Log("Called");

        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

Heres where I'm trying to listen to it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class CustomerSpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject customerPrefab;
    private CustomerMovement customerMovement;

    private float spawnRate = 2.0f;
    private float spawnRateMax = 2.0f;

    private int maxCustomers = 3;
    private int currentCustomers = 0;


    private void Start()
    {
        customerMovement = customerPrefab.GetComponent<CustomerMovement>();

        customerMovement.OnCustomerLeaves += CustomerMovement_OnCustomerLeaves;
    }

    private void CustomerMovement_OnCustomerLeaves(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Maybe");
    }



    private void Update()
    {
        if (currentCustomers < maxCustomers)
        {
            SpawnCustomers();
        }
    }





    private void SpawnCustomers()
    {
        spawnRate -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (spawnRate <= 0)
        {
            var customer = Instantiate(customerPrefab, transform.position, customerPrefab.transform.rotation);
            customer.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

            currentCustomers++;
            Debug.Log("Customers: " + currentCustomers);

            spawnRate = spawnRateMax;
        }


    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Question was answered. I needed to switch when I grabbed the CustomerMovement script and when I subscribed to the event on it. Instead of at Start(), I did it after the prefab was spawned and it now works.

Comment: what has debugging shown you? im going to guess it never actually equals start pos..

Comment: Everything else in the DestroyCustomer() method runs, i.e. "Called" does get printed to the console and the game object does get set to inactive. I also tried putting a debug.log after DestroyCustomer() and it gets printed to the console too

Comment: Ah you cant sub to an event on a prefab as the prefab is an object that doesnt exist yet.. you need to do it to the instantiated object, so it would be set in spawn...